# «Debug assertion failed» и «Expression invalid null pointer»

Tags: c++

Вылазит такая ошибка:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...321\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\core\Debug\core.exe
>   File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring
>   Line: 930
>
> Expression: invalid null pointer
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion faiilure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

Я очень сильно запутался: один и тот же код работает по разному в 2 программах (в одной все хорошо, в другой - эта ошибка). Что делать?

```
in.open(flname);
string lines;

{
    std::string buff;
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, buff);
        lines += buff + '\n';
    }
    in.close();

    std::cout << "reading the " << name << " file was successfully" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"-----------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    strcpy(mass, lines.c_str()); 
    std::cout << mass << std::endl;
;
```

Если закомментировать `getline`, то все хорошо. Что нужно сделать, чтобы все заработало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверно, добавить проверку открылся ли файл и только потом с ним работать.

```
if (!in.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Error open file." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```